# Is there any way of making my sidenav scrollable on every browser

Tags: html, css, overflow, navbar

I just want to make my sidenav able to scroll.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 900px;">
<ul>

   <h2 style="font-family: SF Compact Display;">Channel Selection</h2>
            <hr>

         <div class="button" style="text-align: center;">
         <button class="myclass" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px;">
               <a href="awebpage.html" class="anotherclass">Awebpage</a>
            </button>


</div>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually it works fine like that but the problem is that if the browser is smaller (like on a smartphone) it does not want to go to the bottom of the div, the scroll ends before.
I don't know how to do it so if someone could help me it'll be super nice!

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: I found the answer: I needed to use the viewport height instead of the 100%

Answer (score 0):

Okay nevermind I found the answer: I needed to use the viewport height instead of %
(`height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100%`)